# Dynamic structures & pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am having some issues with my program in C. The function `create_class_list` is supposed to read students' IDs from an input file, dynamically allocate the memory necessary to store the list of students and initialize the student's ID.

More specifically:

- allocate an array of pointers to `student`.
- allocate memory for each variable of type `student`.
- initialize the member to the proper ID value.
- sets each pointer in the array to point to a variable of type `student`.
- return a pointer to the beginning of the array of pointers to `student`.

Here's the code I have so far:

My structure student:

```
typedef struct{

    int ID;
    int project_grade;
    int exam_grade;
    float course_mark;
    struct student *student;

}student;
```

My class list function:

```
student **create_class_list( char *filename, int *sizePtr )
{
    int i = 0;
    student **StructPtr;
    student *students;

    FILE *input_file = fopen("IDnumbers.txt", "r"); //opens input file for reading
    fscanf(input_file,"%d", sizePtr ); //scans the number of students from input file

    StructPtr = (student**)calloc(*sizePtr, sizeof(student*)); // creates an array of    pointers to student
    student **original = StructPtr; // makes a pointer to the first element
    students = (student*)calloc(*sizePtr, sizeof(student)); // creates an array of type student of 'x' students

    while(i < *sizePtr){

        StructPtr[i] = &students[i];
        fscanf(input_file,"%d",students[i].ID ); //allocates IDs to all students
        students[i].course_mark = 0; //initializes all grades to 0
        students[i].exam_grade = 0; //initializes all grades to 0
        students[i].project_grade = 0; // initializes all grades to 0
        i++; // increments counter
    }

    fclose(input_file); //closes file
    return original; //returns pointer to first element
}
```

And my main test function:

```
int main()
{
    int NumberStudents = 0; // number of students in class
    int i; //counter variable
    student **x;

    x = create_class_list("IDnumbers.txt", &NumberStudents);

    printf("%d\n",(**x).ID);
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is supposed to be the very first student # in the input file. The program compiles, but crashes :/ Any suggestions?

Comment: _program [...] crashes_ is not so precise description of your problem. This is not a site _plz d bug my code_. Where it crashes?

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus I am gonna guess segfault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change one line.

```
fscanf(input_file,"%d", &students[i].ID);
```

since `fscanf`'s arguments are pointers.